# In SQL server, how can I query an Oracle Timestamp column over a Linked server connection?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, linked-server

The query I have made in oracle does not work with linked server with sql server 2008.

> The OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "ORACLE" supplied
>   invalid metadata for column "DATETIME_INS". The data type is not
>   supported.

The query:

```
select * from ORACLE..U_GERAN.CELLSTATS4
```

[image]

What are the modification that must be done to execute the query.

Comment: Would have been nice to have the query and the table concerned.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251238)?

Comment: @Lieven This is remote server can't modify or alter the table

Comment: @DavidBrabant edited to include query and table screenshot as I can't see the structure

Comment: @Kitex - You could verify if what is described applies to you. If it does, you are unfortunatly out of luck if you can't modify the table as *This behavior is by design.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE, 'select cast(DATETIME_INS as DATE) from U_GERAN.CELLSTATS4')
```

You can add the other columns to the query once that column works.

Comment: Well first the openquery makes sure that the sql is executed on the remote server. 
The issue was with the null-ability. So casting to a new data type, before it is sent to the local server makes the meta data explicit and there is no conflict.