# SQL server linked server to oracle 8000 limit

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

I have a query that is longer than 8000 in length I tried to execute it following way but it wouldn't. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9877588/591559) for help.

```
Declare @query1 As varchar(8000)
Declare @query2 As varchar(8000)

    SELECT TOP 1000 * 
    FROM OPENQUERY(OPTIMA,@query1+@query2)
```

The Error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 74
Incorrect syntax near '@query1'.
```

I am not allowed to create view or stored procedure in remote server.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? I'm tempted to say try a stored proc because this seems like bad design as opposed to a problem that needs solving.

Comment: How is this related to Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OPENQUERY()` has a builtin limitation of 8KB on your @query, you also are not allowed to use variables for the inputs (in attempt to circumvent the 8KB limit).

I will still recommend creating a stored proc on your target server and calling it with `OPENQUERY()` that way.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make a new view to the Oracle DB of the your query so you can decrease query length.

Comment: heikkila not allowed to create views :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago, basically i was using 'UNION ALL' to union multiple queries inside the openquery.

My solution to this was to union on the local server instead of the remote server, it didn't increase the number of rows being pulled thought the wire because i was using union all anyway, it just forced me to use multiple openquery statements instead of a single one.

It did the job (since I'm not authorized to do anything on the remote server).
If you can, both **hkf** and Jokke **Heikkilä** have the correct answers, just do an sp or view on the remote server.