# How do I convert an Oracle TIMESTAMP data type to SQL Server DATETIME2 data type while connected via Link Server.?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have tried some examples but so far not working.
I have a `Link Server (SQL Server 2014)` to an `Oracle 12C Database`.

The table contain a datatype TIMESTAMP with data like this:

```
22-MAR-15 04.18.24.144789000 PM
```

When attempting to query this table in SQL Server 2014 via link server I get the following error using this code:

```
SELECT CAST(OracleTimeStampColumn AS DATETIME2(7)) FROM linkServerTable
```

Error:

> Msg 7354, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MyLinkServer" supplied invalid metadata for column "MyDateColumn". The data type is not supported.

While the error is self explanatory, I am not certain how to resolve this.

I need to convert the `timestamp` to `datetime2`. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe these links will help: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869892/sql-server-to-oracle-linked-server-query-error), 
[2](http://drewstechnotes.blogspot.com/2010/05/easy-workaround-for-oracle-linked.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can work around this problem by using `OPENQUERY`.  For me, connecting to Oracle 12 from SQL 2008 over a linked server, this query fails:

```
SELECT TOP 10 TimestampField
FROM ORACLE..Schema.TableName
```

...with this error:

```
The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORACLE" supplied invalid metadata for column "TimestampField". The data type is not supported.
```

This occurs even if I do not include the offending column (which is of type `TIMESTAMP(6)`.  Explicitly casting it to `DATETIME` does not help either.

However, this works:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE, 'SELECT "TimestampField" FROM SchemaName.TableName WHERE ROWNUM <= 10')
```

...and the data returned flows nicely into a `DATETIME2()` field.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve the problem is to create a view in oracle server and convert the `OracleTimeStampColumn` compatible with sql server's `datetime2`datatype. You can change the time format to 24 hours format in oracle server's view and mark the field as varchar. Then you can convert the `varchar2` column to `datetime2` when selecting the column in SQL Server.

> In Oracle Server

```
Create or Replace View VW_YourTableName As 
select to_char(OracleTimeStampColumn , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')      OracleTimeStampColumn from YourTableName
```

> In SQL Server

```
SELECT CAST(OracleTimeStampColumn AS DATETIME2(7)) FROM **linkServerVIEW**
```